# avconv convert .mts using libx264 2 pass

Tags: video

I know there are similar questions around, but unfortunately didn't find answer to my question. 
What I like to achieve is video camera originated videos compress as small as possible with as less as possible quality loss. And resize video from 1080p to 720p (720i).
So to get best result it is advisable to use 2 pass encoding. At this problem I have a problem. When I run 2nd pass I get error:

```
[libx264 @ 0xd9b8a0] constant rate-factor is incompatible with 2pass.
```

I have tried very different configurations, but unfortunately didn't find where is my mistake.
For example:

```
avconv -y -i 00000.MTS -qscale 3 -vcodec libx264 -preset medium -pass 1 -f mp4 /dev/null
avconv -y -i 00000.MTS -qscale 3 -vcodec libx264 -preset medium -pass 2 test.mp4
```

I'd be happy if someone could advise how to achieve my goal, or at least point to my mistake ;)

Thanks!

Comment: Does using presets `slow_firstpass` and `slow` (instead of medium) work?

Comment: Unfortunately something is not right: [libx264 @ 0x8e88a0] Error setting preset/tune slow_firstpass/(null).

Comment: `less /usr/share/avconv/libx264-slow_firstpass.avpreset`   `preset=slow`
`fastfirstpass=1`

Answer (score 1):

I use this script that do what you want.

I hope that you are aviable to remove or to adapt some things

> #
>   # Conversor de vídeos a mp4 (x264) con ffmpeg
>
> # cargarme los log que puedan existir
>   rm *.log -f
>   rm *.mbtree -f
>
> for ARCHIVO in *.MTS ;
>   do
>
> avconv -y -i $ARCHIVO -s hd720 -deinterlace -b 2M -bt 4M -vcodec libx264 -pass 1 -flags +loop -me_method dia -g 250 -qcomp 0.6 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -an /home/jcecilio/BK_MULTIMEDIA/COPIAS_HD/$ARCHIVO.mp4
>
> avconv -y -i $ARCHIVO -s hd720 -deinterlace -b 2M -bt 4M -vcodec libx264 -pass 2 -flags +loop -me_method umh -g 250 -qcomp 0.6 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -acodec libvo_aacenc -ac 2 -ab 128k /home/jcecilio/BK_MULTIMEDIA/COPIAS_HD/$ARCHIVO.mp4
>
> done